# iCalendar timezone definition for DST period

Tags: icalendar

By definition European Summer Time begins at last Sunday of March and ends by last Sunday of October

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe

iCalendar event generated from thunderbird's lightning calendar use this definition of timezone with timestamps from year 1970

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Prague
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Since last Sunday of March and October probably won't be the same day every year, shouldn't there be different date every year?

For example for 2016:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Prague
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
...
DTSTART:20160327T020000
...
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
...
DTSTART:20161030T030000
...
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Is it right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DTSTART` indicates the start date, but after that `RRULE` is used to calculate all the next occurences.

RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3

This means:

1. Recur every year
2. On every 3rd month
3. On the last sunday of that month